# how to set timer_ticker to sleep until the process is completed in the background

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker

I have a problem with timerTick() because it executes every 0.5 seconds, for me it's ok because he checks every 0.5 seconds for connectetCard(), now if so he should assign it The 5 seconds that I in _bw.DoWork assigned to run, how can I set timerTick() to fire again, but only when the process in backgroundWorker is completed.

This is my code:

```
public FormMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SelectDevice();
            establishContext();
            timerBatch.Start();
            _bw = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };

        }   

private void timerBatch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (connectCard())
            {
                cardUID = getcardUID();
                if (cardUID != "Error")
                {
                    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            personData = db.Persons.Where(x => x.BATCH_ID == cardUID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (maDaten == null)
                            {
                                labelInfo.Text = "Batch invalid.";
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                person = db.Person.Where(x => x.LPE_ID == personData.MA_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                _bw.DoWork += _bw_DoWork;
                                _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
                                _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
                                _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                            }                         
                        }
                        catch (Exception es)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
                        }

                    };
                }
            }
        }

  private void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i -= 1)
            {
                if (_bw.CancellationPending) { 
                    e.Cancel = true; return; 
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true; return;
                }
                _bw.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }            
        }

   private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            labelInfo.Text = "Hello " + person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName + " " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();

        }

  private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            labelInfo.Text = labelInfo.Text.Trim();
        }
```

Comment: Consider using `Monitor` to effectively lock when the process is in flight.

Comment: @mjwills ok, interesting recommendation, could any example please?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` has a `RunWorkerCompleted` event, which fires when the work is done. You could use this to set a flag that you can check against in your timer callback.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks for the reply, could you please give me a little help on how to do this?

Comment: Sure. I didn't notice earlier that you already have an event handler for `RunWorkerCompleted`. Since you do it should just be a matter of introducing a `bool backgroundWorkerRunning;`, set that to `true` right before the `RunWorkerAsync` call, then test for it at the top of the timer call back, with `if (backgroundWorkerRunning) return;`. The completion callback should set the flag to `false`, of course.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for the reply and your hard work, please if it is not a problem for you to write it in the answer to the question, opposite my code to correct it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public FormMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SelectDevice();
            establishContext();
            timerBatch.Start();
            _bw = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };

        }   

//CHANGE:
bool backgroundworkerRunning = false;

private void timerBatch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //CHANGE:
            if (backgroundworkerRunning)
              return;

            if (connectCard())
            {
                cardUID = getcardUID();
                if (cardUID != "Error")
                {
                    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            personData = db.Persons.Where(x => x.BATCH_ID == cardUID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (maDaten == null)
                            {
                                labelInfo.Text = "Batch invalid.";
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                person = db.Person.Where(x => x.LPE_ID == personData.MA_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                _bw.DoWork += _bw_DoWork;
                                _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
                                _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
                                //CHANGE:
                                backgroundworkerRunning = true; 
                                _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                            }                         
                        }
                        catch (Exception es)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
                        }

                    };
                }
            }
        }

  private void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i -= 1)
            {
                if (_bw.CancellationPending) { 
                    e.Cancel = true; return; 
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true; return;
                }
                _bw.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }            
        }

   private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            labelInfo.Text = "Hello " + person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName + " " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();

        }

  private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //CHANGE:
            backgroundworkerRunning = false; 
            labelInfo.Text = labelInfo.Text.Trim();
        }
```

Comment: I changed the code, it works better, it's not only clear to me why he does 5 times countdown 5,4,3,2,1 (repeats all the time), after the first countdown, I should display labelinfo.trim.text.

Comment: That's a different issue. I can't _run_ your code, obviously. You'll have to investigate and make appropriate changes yourself. Post another question if you get completely stuck.